# Can I add pallet-contracts in substrate-node-template?

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet-contracts

Is there a way to add a pallet-contracts to substrate-node-template?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can find a guide on how to do that [here](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/pallet-design/contracts-pallet/). If you only want to play around with contracts locally I recommend using [substrate-contracts-node](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node).

Comment: I already tried that.  It does not work on the substrate-node-template repository.  Some version problem.  The guide also did not provide what version we should add to the Cargo file.  The substrate-contracts-node is not good for production, the block creation is not normal.